# mamp live code editing for static

Tags: php, mamp

I'm coding/editing my project is uses php code so I have to us MAMP a local server. The problem is that when I make a change to my code and refresh my page none of it comes into effect I've even checked the page source on the console and it is the non-edited code. Is in my MAMP settings?

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. You might want to add some code. It makes it easier for the SO community to reproduce your query.

Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you either are not saving the edit or saving it to a different location and not on the document root of your site